# Looking for picture of "tzadikkim in sukkah"

Tags: product-recommendation, rabbis, sukkah, noy-decorations

I recently saw a noy-sukkah, it was a picture of many tzaddikim (chasidic rebbis and litvish gedolim) gathered around a table in a large sukkah, with the head of the table empty (I gather it's moshiach's seat).
Is anyone familiar with such a picture (and where I can get one)? (the owner of the sukkah I saw it in got it as a gift many years ago...)

Comment: not quite https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moetzes_Gedolei_HaTorah#/media/File:%D7%93%D7%92%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%A9%D7%9A.jpg

Comment: Something like this? https://www.judaicaplace.com/laminated-sukkah-poster-sphardi-gedolim-learning-together-20-x-28/lp868/?gclid=CjwKCAjwkvWKBhB4EiwA-GHjFo30pDtHEcvrX_A3TRaPzMm_0YzSa1r0ll-p4pHmfIXR7qk1R4IpRhoCF4oQAvD_BwE